Subtree-scoped #+latex_header: ... for org-latex-preview
In a large org file of latex snippets, I have many #+latex_header: \usepackage{X} commands.
org-latex-preview includes all \usepackage{X} commands when previewing a snippet. But some of these latex packages are incompatible.
Is it possible to use subtree :properties: to specify something analagous to #+latex_header: \usepackage{X} that only has subtree scope?

I don't think so. You would have to do it programatically: e.g. let-bind org-latex-packages-alist to something safe around the call to org-latex-preview.

I describe one possible way to implement something like what you describe - there are many ways of course (and perhaps the best way is to ask the developers to add the feature ;-) - they might decline, or ask you to implement it and submit a patch, but you never know...)
The idea here is to use a property as a trigger: if the current section includes the property LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES, then a modified function can use the value of the property to calculate a value for org-latex-packages-alist that will include only the packages named in the property: that way you can override the global values for this section. Of course, you don't want to change the global value, just override it for rendering the preview of this section; IOW, we will let-bind the value of this variable around a call to org-latex-preview (as I suggested in my comment).
So we will write a new function my/org-latex-preview that will check for the property, munge it appropriately, let-bind org-latex-packages-alist to the munged value (and also let-bind any other variables as necessary) and call org-latex-preview in that context. If no such property is found in the current section, we will call org-latex-preview directly.
Here's the function:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer

  (defun make-org-latex-packages-alist (l)
    (mapcar (lambda (x) (list "" x t)) l))

  (defun my/org-latex-preview (&optional arg)
    (interactive "P")
    (let ((local-packages  (org-entry-get nil "LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES" nil)))
      (if local-packages
          (let ((org-latex-packages-alist (make-org-latex-packages-alist (split-string local-packages)))
                (org-latex-default-packages-alist nil))
            (message "Local packages: %S" org-latex-packages-alist)
            (org-latex-preview arg))
        (message "No local package list")
        (org-latex-preview arg))))

#+end_src


Some notes:

Put point in the LaTeX fragment you want to preview and say M-x my/org-latex-preview. Or you can bind it to a key of your choice.

The function works at the immediate section level, not at the subtree level: it asks for the value of the property in this section only, by turning off inheritance completely (do C-h f org_entry_get for details). So it will not look for the property in the subtree above, it will only look in the current section (that's why I called it LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES with the emphasis on LOCAL): it is not quite what you asked for.

These things are difficult to debug: org-latex-preview cleans up the TeX file that is produced and all the associated files that the TeX processor produces (.aux file, .log file, etc.) The message calls above are small debugging aids to reassure you that it works, but they don't stick around for long in the echo area: they get overwritten immediately. One way to make them last longer is to sit idly for a second or two (do C-h f sit-for for details), but they are also added to the *Messages* buffer, so I prefer to not use sit-for: if I need to, I can check the buffer to make sure the right message was produced:


Note, BTW, that properties can accumulate their values by using the syntax :<PROPNAME>+: VALUE so you can build LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES incrementally if you prefer:
* Preview
:PROPERTIES:
:LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES: amsmath 
:LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES+: graphicx color
:END:

The property =LOCAL_LATEX_PREVIEW_PACKAGES= will provide the package
list for the preview of LaTeX fragments in this section.  The global
valus of =org-latex-default-packages-alist= and
=org-latex-packages-alist= will be /overridden/ by this property as
long as you use the =my/org-latex-preview= function (see below)
instead of the standard =org-latex-preview= function.


 \[ \int_\infty^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi} \]


Great suggestions. As you say, there are many variations for how this can be implemented. I think I can get something along the lines of your code to meet my needs. Btw, it seems odd that "In-Buffer Settings" (with #+) are often used to implement features, when Properties serve the same purpose in a more powerful way (can control their scope, can do :<PROPNAME>+:). Why did org end up with two systems seemingly doing the same thing?

Historical accidents: properties were a later addition than keywords and by the time they  could more of less replace them, it was not deemed possible to get rid of keywords.

E.g. property drawers at top level were added in version 9.4 (Sep. 2020) - see the release notes.
